# my sql query don't work

Tags: java, mysql, database, select

i have one problem with database in java

my code is ( its only one small part of my project)

```
    public void Read_from_DB(int exhibition_id){
            Statement stmt = null;
            Connection connect = null;

            try {
                connect=MYConnection.new_connection();
                stmt = connect.createStatement();
                QuestionCatalog.get_QuestionCatalog_instance().setShow_quest(new ArrayList<Question>());
                String  sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE Selection=0 AND exhibition_id="+exhibition_id;
                //System.out.println(sql);
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                System.out.println("!");
                System.out.println("->"+rs.getFetchSize());
                while(rs.next()){
                    Question jd=new Question();
                    System.out.println("!!!");
                    jd.setQuestion_id(rs.getInt("Question_id"));
                    jd.setQuestion(rs.getString("Question"));
                    jd.setQuestion(rs.getString(exhibition_id));
                    jd.getOption_2().setContent(rs.getString("Content2"));
        QuestionCatalog.get_QuestionCatalog_instance().getShow_quest().add(jd);
                    System.out.println("size"+QuestionCatalog.get_QuestionCatalog_instance().getShow_quest().size());
MYConnection.close_connection(stmt, connect);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
```

when i execute this code it dosent work
my database table name is "question"
but when i change the name in this query to "Question" , don't get any error 
then i think it doesn't execute my query,my main is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DB_question d=new DB_question();
        d.Read_from_DB(1);
    }
```

and "MYConnection.new_connection();" in part on of code return a connection,( i test it in another class it work)

the result in console is :

```
SELECT * FROM Question WHERE Selection=0 AND exhibition_id=1
!
->0
```

it haven't show "!!!"that is result of "System.out.println("!!!");"
then i think it doesnt work :|
thanks

p.s the picture of my db
[picture](http://oi41.tinypic.com/8yre6f.jpg)

Comment: Try passing the above query directly to the db. What result do you get?

Comment: @Marty McVry : nothing, i say the result of sysout in my main, in my database nothing happen , when i write wrong qury it doesn't give me any error !!!

Comment: Show us some sample data.

Comment: your mean is data of my db? or! data of where?  :|

Comment: You probably have no questions in your mysql table with the Selection=0 and exhibition_id=1, therefore your select statment returns 0 rows.

Comment: no , i have :| i have three row in my db its my picture of db table

Comment: its the picture of my db http://oi41.tinypic.com/8yre6f.jpg

Comment: How could it give you an error: you're catching Exception, and completely ignore it. Drop the catch block, are at least add `e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException(e);` in the catch block.

Comment: Is the MySQL installed on a Linux box? Then case of tables and columns matters... `Question` != `question`

Comment: `ResultSet#getFetchSize()` does not return the number of elements in the result set...

Comment: @ Michael : yes i know but i don't give any error when i change the question with Question, i think  maybe ResultSet#getFetchSize() return the number of element , thanks :)

Comment: @ JB Nizet : i cashe my excenption in MYConnection class , i forget to add the MYConnection.close_connection(stmt, connect); code to my code , i do this know , but nothing happen

Comment: I don't care where you catch more exceptions. The problem is precisely that you're catching exceptions that should NOT be caught, and ignoring the exception completely. Add exactly the code I gave in my previous comment to the catch block of `Read_from_DB()`, and tell us what happens. Exceptions should not be caught, unless you can do something useful to handle them. Ignoring an exception is wrong, always.

Comment: its work thanks , i move the  MYConnection.close_connection(stmt, connect); to after of cache block then work! i cache the exeptions , but i dont know how can i  ,normally printstacktrace it and use exception to find  error of my code!

Comment: I told you twice how to see the exception: remove the catch block completely, or add this to the catch block: `e.printStackTrace(); throw new RuntimeException(e);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is improper output on case sensitive names on table names or column names. Am I right?

As far as I know, reserved words like `SELECT`, `FROM`, etc. are case in-sensitive in all `OS'`s. And all other user defined object names are case-sensitive, in *`*ix OS`* environment. But not in in *`Windows OS`* environment.

But all RDBMS configurations should be allowing case-insensitivity for cross platform deployment. This is the reason why your change from `question` to `Question` did not throw an error.

**And regarding the outcome of your query**:
I fear you have tested your query on different databases or servers. They might not have same data and hence always not entering into `while( rs....` loop.

Change your code as below and see what the output is:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
System.out.println("!");  
System.out.println("->"+rs.getFetchSize());  

rs.beforeFirst();  
rs.last();  
int rowCount = rs.getRow();  
System.out.println( "---> rowCount: " + rowCount );  
rs.beforeFirst();  

while( ...
```

**Also refer to**:
[***DBMS Identifiers and Case Sensitivity - MysQL***](http://www.alberton.info/dbms_identifiers_and_case_sensitivity.html#p9)

Comment: emm yes i know , but when i change the sensitive of my table name and table row it doesn't give me any error

Comment: my output is: Creating statement...
SELECT * FROM question WHERE Selection=0 AND quest_poll_id=1
!
->0
---> rowCount: 3
!!!